# Using Greek letters with the Nath package

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode-math

I'd like to use the Nath package together with a math font which supports Greek letters, while retaining the default font for the non-Greek letters. Is this possible?

I tried compiling the following document with xelatex.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfsfit/{greek,Greek}]{lmmath.otf}
\RequirePackage{nath}
\begin{document}
$$\tilde{T}α$$
\end{document}
```

It gave me an error:

```
Nath as of 21 March 2003 
Implementing NAtural maTH notation
) (./test2.aux) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
! Internal error: bad native font flag
```

If I remove the range option to setmathfont, or the tilde, the document compiles.

Comment: I don't think so. If I say `\setmathfont{XITS Math}`, just for a try, it works. Why not simply use `\setmathfont{lmmath.otf}`?

Comment: I tried that, but saw that it didn't provide some symbols I was using, so commands like notin would give blank output.Is it possible to fall back on the default font in these cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This input file works and shows `\notin`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{nath}

\begin{document}
$$\tilde{T}α\notin X$$

\end{document}
```